# Finding the median value on a probability density function

Tags: probability, integration, median

Quick question here that I cannot find in my textbook or online.

I have a probability density function as follows:

$\begin{cases}
0.04x & 0 \le x < 5 \\
0.4 - 0.04x & 5 \le x < 10 \\
0 & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$

Now I understand that for the median, the *value* of the integral must be $0.5$. We can set the integrals from negative infinity to *m* where *m* represents the median and solve. However, there are 2 functions here so how would i do that? In the answers that I was provided, the prof. simply takes the first function and applies what I said.

How/why did he do that?

Help would be greatly appreciated! Thank you :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know, let's find out.  Maybe the median is in the $[0,5]$ part. Maybe it is in the other part. To get some insight, let's find the probability that our random variable lands between $0$ and $5$. This is
$$\int_0^5(0.04)x\,dx.$$
Integrate. We get $0.5$. What a lucky break! There is nothing more to do. The median is $5$.

Well, it wasn't entirely luck. **Graph** the density function. (We should have done that to begin with, geometric insight can never hurt.) We find that the density function is  **symmetric** about the line $x=5$. So the median must be $5$.

**Remark:** Suppose the integral had turned out to be $0.4$. Then to reach the median, we need $0.1$ more in area. Then the median $m$ would be the number such that $\int_5^m (0.4-0.04x)\,dx=0.1$.

Comment: Ah I see. So it is a little of bit a guess I suppose. Alright great thank you! I was confused as I thought it followed a strict rule!

Comment: It really is integration, but because there are two different formulas, the exact process depends on where the median is. We tried to find out, and "bumped" into the median. In a comment at the end, I explain what one would do if the integral to $5$ had turned out to be, say, $0.4$.

Comment: Yes I understood that! Very excellent explanation thanks!

Comment: Why did you multiply the equation by 10 before integrating it?

Comment: @user1561358: Thank you, I didn't really multiply by $10$, just mistakenly wrote $0.4$ in the integral instead of $0.04$. But I was *thinking $0.04$, and the integral from $0$ to $5$ of $0.04x$ is indeed $0.5$, so the rest was right.